# Find text in DB without knowing what table or column?

Tags: database, ms-access, full-text-search

I have a DB in MS Access 2010. I am not the creator of the DB and have no way to contact him to ask this question. It's a big database with many tables and records, and the names of the tables and columns are very non descriptive. Basically, I am trying to find which table/column is storing certain data, and I specifically know the value of the data. For example: I know there is a customer that is called 'ABCDEF' because I just added it using the software that uses the database. Now, I need to know what table is storing this customer data.

Is this possible at all? A way to go table by table, record by record, field by field of the whole database and compare it with my string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```vb
Public Sub FindInAllTables(ByVal s As String)
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef, fld As DAO.Field
    Dim pattern As String

    pattern = "*" & s & "*"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
        If (tdf.Attributes And dbSystemObject) = 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rs = tdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
            If err.Number = 0 Then
                On Error GoTo 0
                Debug.Print "Scanning [" & tdf.Name & "]  ";
                Do Until rs.EOF()
                    For Each fld In rs.Fields
                        If fld.Value Like pattern Then
                            Debug.Print
                            Debug.Print "  Match in [" & tdf.Name & "].[" & _
                                fld.Name & "] ===> """ & fld.Value & """";
                            Exit Do
                        End If
                    Next fld
                    If rs.AbsolutePosition Mod 1000 = 999 Then
                        Debug.Print ".";
                    End If
                    rs.MoveNext
                Loop
                Debug.Print
                rs.Close
            Else
                On Error GoTo 0
                Debug.Print "Cannot open table [" & tdf.Name & "]"
            End If
        End If
    Next tdf
    db.Close
End Sub
```

This finds strings contained in any part of a field. If you prefer to find whole fields only, replace `If fld.Value Like pattern Then` by `If fld.Value = s Then`.

Comment: When I try to execute it in the immediate window it says "Run-time error '3167': Record is deleted."

Comment: Strange. It does not happen with my DB. Is someone else working on the same DB at the same time? Try adding some error handling (`On Error Resume Next` or the like).

Comment: I tried the two methods, and both throw the "Run-time error '3167': Record is deleted." Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: It breaks in the line "If fld.Value = s Then". If I add fld.Value to watch, I can see that its Value is <Record is deleted.>. I just saw your latest response. How would that error handling be exactly? VB is like chinese to me.

Comment: If the tables are linked ODBC-tables (see [PRB: Explaining "Record is deleted" error accessing ODBC table](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172339/en-us)) you could try to open the recordset with `Set rs = tdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)`.

Comment: When I try to use dbOpenSnapshot to open the recordset, it says "Run-time error '3146': ODBC -call failed".

Comment: Stupid question, but can you open the tables manually? They might not be connected if you are not runnning the application.

Comment: Yes, I can open the tables and see the data in them.

Comment: Try different parameters in `OpenRecordset`: `dbOpenTable`, `dbOpenDynamic`, `dbOpenDynaset`, `dbOpenSnapshot`, `dbOpenForwardOnly`. By the way, what kind of backend database are you accessing?

Comment: I don't know what causes the problem. Therefore I added some error handling to the code that copes with tables that cannot be opened. E.g. linked tables that are not available or tables for which you do not have the access rights for.

Comment: I tried your latest code with the error handling and after showing the first "Cannot open table XXXXX" message, Access freezes and goes to "Not Responding". My PC is pretty powerful, so I think that maybe Access just can't handle so much calculating (or maybe after 16 hours it pops up the results, but it doesn't seem like it will). If you have any other idea or think this is a different problem, let me know. If not, I appreciate your efforts very much!

Comment: It's very hard without having the database at hand. Of cause, if you have many very long tables the operation can last. I added some print statements in order to get more information. The name of the table being scanned is printed. After each 1000 record a dot `"."` is printed. This will help you to see whether access got stuck or is working as expected. If there is still a problem, it would be a good idea to look at the code of the original application (if possible). May there is a specific login code that is needed in order to be able to access your DB.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that your Sub actually DID work! Access did get frozen and would not respond for a couple of hours, but when it was done processing it did print the desired information. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to locate the table containing the text, which means that either that data is not stored in a table (which doesn't make any sense, since it is getting stored somewhere) or it is in one of the tables that won't let me open (there's a lot of them). Anyhow, your help was very valuable. Thanks!

Comment: Try to use the `Linked Table Manager` to re-link the tables that you cannot open. Right-click on a table and choose `Linked Table Manager`.